# Javascript - why is my hide/show html code not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to click on the class questionBox and hide/show the class answers, so i have created an array of classes using querySelectorAll to select questionBox classes, then loop via the arrays using for Each loop, then i created another variable each to house each questions and answers, then i attached an eventlistener function to the questions class, such that when you click on the class it hides/shows the answers

Here is a sample code

HTML

```
<div class="questionBox">
 <div class="questions">
  <p>How many team members can I invite?</p>
                        <!-- <div class="arrows"></div> -->
 </div>
 <div class="answers">You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team members for the Premium plan.</div>
 </div>
 
<div class="questionBox">
 <div class="questions">
  <p>How many team members can I invite?</p>
                        <!-- <div class="arrows"></div> -->
 </div>
 <div class="answers">You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team members for the Premium plan.</div>
 </div>
    
<div class="questionBox">
 <div class="questions">
  <p>How many team members can I invite?</p>
                        <!-- <div class="arrows"></div> -->
 </div>
 <div class="answers">You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team members for the Premium plan.</div>
 </div>
    
<div class="questionBox">
 <div class="questions">
  <p>How many team members can I invite?</p>
                        <!-- <div class="arrows"></div> -->
 </div>
 <div class="answers">You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team members for the Premium plan.</div>
 </div>
```

```
css
.questionBox{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.answers{
    display: none;
}
```

```
js

let toggleBox = document.querySelectorAll(".questionBox");

toggleBox.forEach(item =>{
    let x = document.querySelector(".questions");
    let y = document.querySelector(".answers");

    x.addEventListener('click', function(){
        if(y.style.display === "none"){
            y.style.display = "block"
        }
        else{
            y.style.display = "none"
        }
    })
})
```

Any help please

Comment: Are you basically looking for an [Accordion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#accordion-example)?

Comment: Is the js part located above or below the HTML part?

Comment: you can put before </body> to unblock render blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the selectors inside the loop are not related to the looped item:

```js
let toggleBox = document.querySelectorAll(".questionBox");

toggleBox.forEach(item =>{
    let x = item.querySelector(".questions");
    let y = item.querySelector(".answers");

    x.addEventListener('click', function(){
        if(y.style.display === "none"){
            y.style.display = "block"
        }
        else{
            y.style.display = "none"
        }
    })
})
```

```css
.questionBox{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.answers{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="questionBox">
 <div class="questions">
  <p>How many team members can I invite?</p>
                        <!-- <div class="arrows"></div> -->
 </div>
 <div class="answers">You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team members for the Premium plan.</div>
 </div>
 
<div class="questionBox">
 <div class="questions">
  <p>How many team members can I invite?</p>
                        <!-- <div class="arrows"></div> -->
 </div>
 <div class="answers">You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team members for the Premium plan.</div>
 </div>
    
<div class="questionBox">
 <div class="questions">
  <p>How many team members can I invite?</p>
                        <!-- <div class="arrows"></div> -->
 </div>
 <div class="answers">You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team members for the Premium plan.</div>
 </div>
    
<div class="questionBox">
 <div class="questions">
  <p>How many team members can I invite?</p>
                        <!-- <div class="arrows"></div> -->
 </div>
 <div class="answers">You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team members for the Premium plan.</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What is the difference in your answer? I see that the code is exact same

Comment: `document.querySelector()` vs `item.querySelector()`

Comment: wow thanks so much, @netizen it solved the problem, it was an over sight

Comment: @netizen another challenge, this code works on small screen perfectly, but it does not work on a large screen, in fact the cursor effect upon hover does not work on a large screen but works fine on a small screen

Comment: @seun I've just ran the snippet full screen and it works for me. I need to click twice on a question, but that's another issue in your code, mine was only to show the error with the selectors